# What programming language uses commands like mob/verb?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

```
mob/verb/test(N as num)
```

What language is this code from?

Answer (score 11):

That looks to be the 'Dream Maker' programming language from BYOND, a gaming service:  http://www.byond.com/docs/notes/285.html.  It uses a piece of software, also known as Dream Maker, to create its games.  http://en.allexperts.com/e/b/by/byond.htm

Specifically, the `mob/verb` in this example refers to creating a verb for a mob (an abbreviation for creature/NPC in games), and calling it test.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Dream Maker (DM) language. See:

- http://www.byond.com/
- http://files.byondhome.com/iainperegrine/arcana/dm4.html

The latter page, entitled "Dream Maker 4.0" has examples containing the exact same code snippet shown in the question.